# 2D Push Forward/Sprinting effect?

Tags: animation

A few weeks ago i watched a video and found a really cool 2d push forward/sprinting effect which looks like the following :

[image: sprintEffect]

How this is made ? Is this effect included into the animation or just spawned as randomly sized dust clouds ? And how this would work ? Is there any pseudo code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [2d Particle / Effect Animation / Ermitter](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/130876/2d-particle-effect-animation-ermitter)

Comment: Sorry, posted twice, deleted the first post

Comment: The effect is most definitely not included in the animations. It is likely instantiated as the player runs. Depending on your game engine (or lack there of), the code will vary drastically from simply toggling a premade particle system (Unity), to writing your own meshes and instancing them (opengl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its difficult to see what you mean by 'effect' with a still image. I'll assume you mean the smoke effect.

If so..
 Have a particle effect which takes random parameters for movement, fade out (alpha), scale and lifespan. When your character is sprinting, spawn a smoke effect at the characters coordinate using random parameters for movement, fade and lifespan. Sometimes lifespan may be determined by alpha ( when its fully faded out it dies)